# Degenerate Polygon

Tags: .fbx, unreal-engine

I lost all of my FBX files so I’m having to remodel them in Blender and import in Unreal.

The parts are pretty basic shapes just cubes with cylinders at different sizes. I’ve imported three with no problem, but then on the 4th import it gives me the error:

> Mesh Name: [Block] part name: [Cylinder] could not be created because all of its polygons are degenerate.”

So after trying to remake the model in a fresh Blender project to no avail, and some quick detective work, I’ve noticed that it’s only the cylinder meshes that give me this error.

I went back into Blender, started a brand new project, added a default cylinder mesh, exported the default cylinder mesh to FBX, and then tried to import and again I am met with the *could not be created because all of its polygons are degenerate* error.

I then went back into Blender in *Edit Mode*, *Mesh > Clean Up > Degenerate Dissolve* and dissolved anything within a 1mm radius and still I get the degenerate polygons issue.

If I don’t “join” my meshes in Blender and export the FBX, then every part of the model except for the cylinders get imported successfully.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your import scale in unreal is at least 1, not 0.

That's what I was doing wrong, had accidentally reset my scale to 0 from when I had it at 10.